# Network Adapter Error when connecting to Oracle with SQL Developer on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

Keep getting the following error:
"Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"
when trying to connect to the Oracle database on my local machine. I've successfully logged on before, but when I try and rejoin a connection it presents this error.

I've tried re-installing, connecting as sys or other usernames, but the error keeps returning.

Comment: What are the values in the 'properties' dialog for this particular connection? (connection type, etc)  Have you confirmed that the database is actually started?

Comment: Can you shed more light on ORA-ERROR-CODE. Oracle always has error code.